# RubyOnRails project deployment halted due to "rake aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for BigDecimal:Class" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

While trying to deploy an old RubyOnRails project, I receive this error in console:

```
Nov 27 06:54:15 PM  rake aborted!
Nov 27 06:54:15 PM  NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for BigDecimal:Class
```

While I have done research, the cause of this error confounds me, which is why I am asking for help to find out any possible cause of error. I know that it probably has something to do with gem versioning, so here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
ruby '3.0.1'

gem 'bigdecimal', '>=2.5.5'

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

gem 'thin'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '0.17.0'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem "haml-rails", "~> 0.5.2"

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Rails 4 is never going to work well with Ruby 3. `BigDecimal::new` was deprecated in Ruby 2.6 and removed in 2.7; however Rails 4.1 was designed to work with Ruby 2.0, and reached EOL more than 6 years ago.

Comment: I took your suggestion and rollbacked Ruby to 2.6.0, however I face the same problem...should I rollback Ruby even further or BigDecimal (or should I update to Rails 5)?

Comment: If upgrading to rails 5 is an option then you should absolutely do so.